# hls.js in chrome using vue doesnt update m3u8 playlist

Tags: javascript, vue.js, live-streaming, m3u8, hls.js

I want to deploy a live streaming video in m3u8 format, in mounted() function, using:

```
if(Hls.isSupported()) {
    let video = this.$refs.videoPrueba2;
    let hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource('./HLS/out.m3u8');
    hls.attachMedia(video);
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function () {
        video.play();
    });
}
```

However, when the page loads, the player loads every video in the playlist included up until the moment and stops playing. It doesn't play the new ts files being created. I have to CTRL + SHIFT + R (delete cache and reload the page) to see the video with the new ts files.

I created the .m3u8 file with the following ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i short.mp4 -c:v h264 -flags +cgop -g 30 -vf scale=-1:360 -hls_list_size 0 ./HLS/out.m3u8
```

I tried putting:

```
hls.loadSource('./HLS/out.m3u8');
```

in a setInterval but it didn't help.

Could this be a memory leak caused by vue and loadSource doesn't know where to load from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem related to the browser's cache, it was solved by replacing:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'streams'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));
```

with:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'streams'), { maxAge: 0 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

When I worked with video m3u8 in vue3, I used this package

[vue-hls-video-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-hls-video-player)

Probably, ready solution could solve your problem

```
  npm i vue-hls-video-player

  <VideoPlayer
    type="default"
    @pause="processPause"
    previewImageLink="poster.webp"
    link="videoLink.m3u8"
    :progress="30"
    class="customClassName"
  />

  <VideoPlayer
    type="preview"
    previewImageLink="poster.webp"
    link="videoLink.m3u8"
    class="customClassName"
  />
```